# unable to updated/deleted/retrieve Calendar Events using GAE Java API with two legged authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

Hi I am writing a  connector tool using GAE Java which adds,updates, deletes and
retrieves calendar events.I am using 2 legged authentication for the same. I am able to add new events successfully using 2 legged authentication but not able to
update, delete or retrieve events using the same.

It gives following error while I try to do either of update/delete/retrieve operation on calendar event.

com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: OK

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The same code works fine if I remove OAuth specific code and just use service.setUserCredentials() method.

Kindly help me out to resolve this issue. Please revert back in case
more information on this is required.

Thanks in advance.

-Nirzari 
Below is the code snippet

```
//Code for getCalendarEvents
String url = FEED_URL + "?xoauth_requestor_id="
                                        + "u...@domain.com";
URL postUrl = new URL(url);
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
                oauthParameters.setScope(Scope);
                oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(ConsumerKey);
                oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(secret);

CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("getAppointments");
OAuthSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);
CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(postUrl);
CustomParameter customParameter = new CustomParameter("showdeleted",
"true");
myQuery.addCustomParameter(customParameter);
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery,
                                        CalendarEventFeed.class);

//Code for Update Appointment
String url = FEED_URL + "?xoauth_requestor_id="                                       +
"usern...@domain.com";

URL postUrl = new URL(url);
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setScope(Scope);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(ConsumerKey);
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(secret);
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("updateAppointment");
OAuthSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);
CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(postUrl);
myQuery.setExtendedPropertyQuery(new ExtendedPropertyMatch(
                                        "Prop_Name", value));
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(myQuery,
                                        CalendarEventFeed.class);

if (resultFeed != null && resultFeed.getEntries().size() > 0) {
CalendarEventEntry matchEntry = (CalendarEventEntry) resultFeed
                                                .getEntries().get(0);
updateCalendarEntry(matchEntry, description, title, start, end,                startTime, endTime, location, priavte, guestList);
matchEntry.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible causes could be that user email is not URL encoded (@ should be encoded as %40). Use this code, that handles URL encoding automatically:

```
query.addCustomParameter(new CustomParameter("xoauth_requestor_id", userEmail));
```

rather than append parameter manually.

Another possible cause is that your app doesn't have granted access to Calendar by administrator of Google Apps domain, to which the user belongs. You can check it on this page: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/DOMAIN-NAME/ManageOauthClients.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply adding query.addCustomParameter(new CustomParameter("xoauth_requestor_id", userEmail)); just worked for me.